# Webpack - webpack-dev-server: command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I am working on a React webapp using webpack, loosely alongside [this tutorial](http://fredguest.com/2015/03/06/building-a-stateless-rails-api-with-react-and-twitter-oauth/).

Accidentally, I added the node_modules folder to my git. I then removed it again using `git rm -f node_modules/*`.

Now, when I try starting the webpack server, I get the following error:

```
> webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.dev.config.js --content-base public/ --progress --colors

sh: webpack-dev-server: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "devserve"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! Blabber@0.0.1 devserve: `webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.dev.config.js --content-base public/ --progress --colors`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

At first I thought it was only my project, but then I checked out the code checkpoints of the tutorial: same error! So something seems to be messed up globally.

Here's what I tried so far:

- `rm node_modules` and reinstall with `npm install`
- `npm cache clean` as someone mentioned regarding [this issue on github](https://github.com/bradleyboy/yarsk/issues/4)
- install webpack globally with `npm install -g webpack`
- completely delete node and npm from my system (using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1720523)) and reinstall using brew

The error message still persists. What else can I try?

PS: The content of `webpack.dev.config.js` is:

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development")
    }
  })
);

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of the file `webpack.dev.config.js`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and webpack-dev-server is definitely right there in the folder

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Okay, it was easy:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

What confused me that I did not need that at first, probably things changed with a new version.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me without the `-g` flag. So: `npm i webpack-dev-server -g` solved the problem.

Comment: I too required the -g flag

Comment: I also needed to npm install webpack -g because it was not installed globally at first

Comment: It was confusiong because on the webpack page they don't have the -g option in their example. If you dont want to install globally, you can create a script in the package.json and run it through npm run.

Comment: i try uninstall this package using this command "npm uninstall webpack-dev-server -g --save"  but not uninstalled, please let me know how to uninstall this package.

Answer (score 44):

**FYI**, to access any script via command-line like you were trying, you
need to have the script registered as a shell-script *(***or any kind of
script like .js, .rb***)* in the system like these files in the the dir
`/usr/bin` in UNIX. And, system must know where to find them. i.e.
the location must be loaded in `$PATH` array.

---

In your case, the script `webpack-dev-server` is already installed somewhere inside `./node_modules` directory, but system does not know how to access it. So, to access the command `webpack-dev-server`, you need to install the script in **global scope** as well.

```
$ npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

Here, `-g` refers to global scope.

---

However, this is not recommended way because you might face version conflicting issues; so, instead you can set a command in `npm`'s `package.json` file like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.dev.config.js --content-base public/ --progress --colors"
   }
```

This setting will let you access the script you want with simple command

```sh
$ npm start
```

or

```sh
$ yarn start
```

So short to memorize and play. And, `npm` knows the location of the module `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: But when I run `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`,why it said that this is invalid command?I think running `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` is equal to running `npm run dev`

Comment: In the readme for webpack-dev-server - they recommend local vs global install!

Answer (score 17):

The script `webpack-dev-server` is already installed inside ./node_modules directory.
You can either install it again globally by

```
sudo npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

or run it like this

```
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js -d --config webpack.dev.config.js --content-base public/ --progress --colors
```

`.` means look it in current directory.

Answer (score 12):

**Yarn**

I had the problem when running: `yarn start`

It was fixed with running first: `yarn install`

Comment: Simple `yarn install` worked in my case. Not sure what the reason was.

Comment: or `npm i` whichever you prefer

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue but the below steps helped me to get out of it.

1. Installing the 'webpack-dev-server' locally (In the project directory as it was not picking from the global installation)

   npm install --save webpack-dev-server

Can verify whether 'webpack-dev-server' folder exists inside node_modules.

2. Running using npx for running directly

`npx webpack-dev-server --mode development --config ./webpack.dev.js`

`npm run start` also works fine where your entry in package.json scripts should be like the above like without npx.

Answer (score 2):

I found the accepted answer does not work in all scenarios. To ensure it 100% works one must ALSO clear the npm cache. Either directly Goto the cache and clear locks, caches, anonymous-cli-metrics.json; or one can try `npm cache clean`.

Since the author had cleared the cache before trying the recommended solution its possible that failed to make it part of the pre-requisites.

Answer (score 2):

For global installation :
**npm install webpack-dev-server -g**

For local installation
**npm install --save-dev webpack**

When you refer webpack in package.json file, it tries to look it in location node_modules\.bin\

After local installation, file wbpack will get created in location:
\node_modules\.bin\webpack

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same problem after installing VSCode and adding a remote Git repository. Somehow the `/node_modules/.bin` folder was deleted and running `npm install --save webpack-dev-server` in the command line re-installed the missing folder and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I install with `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server` then I set package.json and webpack.config.js like this:
[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACv7E.jpg).

Then I run webpack-dev-server and get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRyiW.jpg).

If I don't use `npm install -g webpack-dev-server` to install, then how to fix it?

I fixed the error `configuration has an unknown property 'colors'` by removing `colors:true`. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with **Yarn**, none of above worked for me, so I simply removed `./node_modules` and run `yarn install` and problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader url-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

npm install webpack-dev-server -g    -- windows OS

Better you use sudo in linux to avoid permission errors

sudo npm install webpack-dev-server -g

You could use sudo npm install webpack-dev-server  --save to add it to package.json.

Sometimes you may require to run the below commands.

npm install webpack-cli --save or npm install webpack-cli -g

Comment: Please don't advice using sudo with npm.

Comment: See why [here](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3)