# webpack-dev-server command not found

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server

I run this command in my project folder

```
    npm install --global webpack webpack-dev-server
```

it return:

```
   /usr/lib

     ├── webpack@1.14.0
     └── webpack-dev-server@1.16.2
```

webpack and webpack-dev-server folders are under /usr/lib/node_modules,  webpack command works, webpack-dev-server command return:

```
 webpack-dev-server: command not found
```

the configure json:

```
  "webpack": "^1.14.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
```

I also tried install in without -g, there is node_modules under the project folder, and .bin folder under node_modules. However webpack-dev-server is out of node_modules folder. I try move webpack-dev-server into .bin. it does not work either.

Comment: I found an alternative way to make it work: run npm and webpack from the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627310

Answer (score 0):

installing packages globally is not good. Package.json does not define globally installed modules. When you run npm install command to setup a project, your project will not know about global modules.

You should install

```
npm i webpack-dev-server --save
```

then you need to add configuration into the webpack.config.js file. this is the related line for webpack-dev-server inside the file

```
 const path=require ("path")

{
    devServer: { contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public") }

}
```

now you need to write  this script on to package.json

```
"scripts":{    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
}
```

this command will run your app

```
npm run dev-server
```