# Next.js:_next/webpack-hmr request 404

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, next.js

This issue's demo repo is https://github.com/hh54188/happy-server/tree/issue-demo

I try to integrate Next.js with Hapi.js as a plugin. Here is my next.js plugin project folder main structure:

```
--plugins
   |--app
        |--pages
            |--app
                |--a.js
        |--handlers
        |--public
             |--dist
        |--index.js
        |--next.config.js
```

And here is index.js main content, most for route register

```
const nextRenderService = next({
  dir: path.join(__dirname)
});

module.exports = {
  name: "AppService",
  version: "0.0.1",
  register: async function(server, options) {
    await nextRenderService.prepare();

    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: `/app/${assetPrefix}/_next/webpack-hmr`,
      handler: nextHandlerWrapper(nextRenderService)
    });

    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: "/app/{param*}",
      handler: defaultHandler(nextRenderService)
    });

    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: `/app/${assetPrefix}/_next/on-demand-entries-ping`,
      handler: nextHandlerWrapper(nextRenderService)
    });

    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: `/app/${assetPrefix}/_next/-/page/{param*}`,
      handler: {
        directory: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, pagesPath),
          listing: true
        }
      }
    });

    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: `/app/${assetPrefix}/_next/{param*}`,
      handler: {
        directory: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, distPath),
          listing: true
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
```

However, when I run the server, and visit http://127.0.0.1:4000/app/a, the page could render success, and most script file could load successful. But the `_next/webpack-hmr` and the `_next/on-demand-entries-ping` requests status is `404`. And I notice the 404 status is from Next.js, not Hapi.js

So what's wrong with my code ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Why are you handling next requests? You only have to define the routes of the application, every else request has to be handled by the next.js default handler.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has arisen right after upgrading nextjs 11 > 12.

This helped me:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -g
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627310/

Answer (score 0):

The `assetPrefix` configuration is for using a CDN only and is global to NextJs ([documentation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#cdn-support-with-asset-prefix)). You don't want to set that for something else, like modifying the NextJs router paths. If you don't plan on using a CDN, just ignore this setting.

```
// in constants/index.js
const assetPrefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" 
    ? "https://cdn.mydomain.com" 
    : "";
```

You also do not want to list all NextJs internal routes and use the NextJs request handler to handle all calls:

```
// index.js
const next = require("next");
const path = require("path");

const nextRenderService = next({
  dir: path.join(__dirname),
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
});

const { defaultHandler, nextHandlerWrapper } = require("./hanlders");

module.exports = {
  name: "AppService",
  version: "0.0.1",
  register: async function(server, options) {
    // https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/custom-server-hapi/server.js
    await nextRenderService.prepare();

    // handle NextJs application requests
    const handler = nextRenderService.getRequestHandler();
    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: "/app/{p*}",
      handler: async ({ raw, url }, h) => {
        await handler(raw.req, raw.res, url);
        return h.close;
      }
    });

    // handle NextJs private routes
    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: "/_next/{p*}" /* next specific routes */,
      handler: nextHandlerWrapper(nextRenderService)
    });

    // Other routes
    server.route({
      method: "GET",
      path: "/{p*}" /* catch all route */,
      handler: defaultHandler(nextRenderService)
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: However, I want to run multiply next.js instances on a single Hapi.js server. So I have to add some prefix to the `_next/` to diff the `_next` request from different Next.js instances

Comment: ok i did not understand that. you should be using 2 separate server then.