# webpack-dev-server isn't working in my project

Tags: webpack

I'm having some issue with my project, when I run `webpack-dev-server` command, it show me not found, even I've installed twice webpack-dev-server!

Thanks!

Comment: are you using webpack4?

Comment: yeah, I'm using webpack4!, `npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server` it successfully install, but later doesn't work!

Comment: have you updated your node and npm?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to copy/paste the exact error message, and the webpack config file, as well as the exact command you are running.

Comment: `node 10.15 && npm 5.8`, what the problem?

Comment: `webpack-dev-server: command not found
`

Comment: You might want to try solutions proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611527/webpack-webpack-dev-server-command-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack - webpack-dev-server: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611527/webpack-webpack-dev-server-command-not-found)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you have installed `webpack`, `webpack-cli` and `webpack-dev-server` the wrong way. You made them `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`. To change that, uninstall them:

```
npm uninstall webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
```

and then install them properly:

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Now, `webpack-dev-server` is in your `node_modules` folder. You can either run it from your terminal with

```
node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
```

or (as @nickbullock said), add a script in your `package.json` file and execute it from your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

webpack dev-server is not installed globally.
please add it your scripts section in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

and then run it from console:
`npm run dev-server`

Also you can install it globally:
`npm install -g webpack-dev-server`
then you can run `webpack-dev-server` command on any project without local installation and adding to the scripts.

If you have global and local webpack-dev-server and using it with scripts, local version will be used.

Comment: now it's working, thanks! but before we could do like that!