# You need to install 'webpack-dev-server' for running 'webpack serve'. - error getting when give npm start in React Application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-start, ajv

[image]

[webpack-cli] You need to install 'webpack-dev-server' for running 'webpack serve'.
Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

I getting error like this when give npm start in React Application.

Comment: Please update your question to include your package.json file, it's impossible to tell whether you've installed webpack-dev-server correctly without the package.json file and the output of the `npm install` command

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your package.json to see if it has been installed?  It is common to mispell something on install and have a different package installed.  Here is a similar thread

[webpack-dev-server isn't working in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029282/webpack-dev-server-isnt-working-in-my-project)