# why 'webpack serve' command isn't not working in my project?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use webpack in my project.
After a few months I've decided to update this project (that is my website), and after `npm install` and `webpack serve` I've encountered these error that I can't solve:

```
> webpack serve

[webpack-cli] You need to install 'webpack-dev-server' for running 'webpack serve'.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ start: `webpack serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried:

- deleting **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and running `npm install` again
- updating packages to the last version
- reinstalling node.js
- solution to [these post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029282/webpack-dev-server-isnt-working-in-my-project), but didn't work for me.

I don't really know why this problem is happening. Oh, and I think it's important to mention that **I was experiencing even more errors (related to python and stuff), but after I install Visual Studio Desktop Development with C++ that was the only error that persisted.**

Comment: The error message is very clear, did you install `webpack-dev-server` package?